# SQlite implementation on Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin.Forms application and I need to be able to manage a DB. I'm developing in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 and I'm following this tutorial dor the SQLite: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt736454.aspx

The problem is that when I get to the point: Figure 6 Generating a Connection String in the Universal Windows Project, that is to say implementing the DatabaseConnection_UWP.cs class. There I get some errors:

```
using LocalDataAccess.UWP;
```

Here it says: The type or namespace name "LocalDataAccess" could not be found (ar you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

And in the line:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DatabaseConnection_UWP))]
```

It says: The type or namespace name "DatabaseConnection_UWP" could not be found (ar you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The code is exactly the same, all I have done is to copy-paste from the tutorial.

Comment: Sounds like LocalDataAccess is in a dll.   Do you need to add a reference?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it following a different tutorial that worked perfectly: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/